# When using open source Chef cookbooks - should we clone or reference in Berksfile?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Say I am building my /my_company_cookbooks collection and I want to use an awesome community cookbook from Github.

I have two options

1. Reference the cookbook from github by adding a line to my Berksfile (cookbook 'graphite', git: 'git://github.com/hw-cookbooks/graphite.git'
   )
2. Local copies - Clone the cookbook into my /my_company_cookbooks folder and keep a local reference to it.

Each strategy seem to have merits and disadvantages.

**Github merits**

- No local copies
- Easy to get fixes done by author

**Github disadvantages**
 - How do I ascertain that my production cookbooks depend on exactly the version of cookbooks which I tested on staging. Author can forget to bump cookbook version while still making code changes. Untested code changes will then reach my production environment

**Local copies merits**
I can test and push to production with 100% certainty & debugging is easier

**Local copies disadvantages**

- How to get updated copies of the cookbook (clone again?)
- I'll have a git repo within a git repo?
- With a local copy, other cookbook developers can modify cloned cookbooks, making it even harder to sync when a new version of cookbook is released on github

Any thoughts or best practices in this matter?

Thanks

Comment: "Github disadvantages - How do I ascertain" -> target the tagged version on github instead of master branch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [Berkshelf documentation](http://berkshelf.com/):

> GitHub Location
>
> As of version 1.0.0, you may now use GitHub shorthand to specify a
>   location.
>
> cookbook "artifact", github: "RiotGames/artifact-cookbook", tag:
>   "0.9.8" Given this example, the artifact cookbook from the RiotGames
>   organization in the artifact-cookbook repository with a tag of 0.9.8
>   will be cloned to the berkshelf.

I assume this remove the disadvantage of github, and then you just have no reason to refrain using it now.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you so much :)

Comment: you should also be using cookbook version constraints in your environment files. especially in production/live

Answer (score 3):

Where possible consume the cookbooks from the community "supermarket" repository. For example the following will retrieve the latest version of graphite:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook "graphite"
```

The documentation shows that this cookbook is managed by the [heavywater dudes](https://supermarket.chef.io/users/heavywater):

- https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/graphite

Why? When consuming cookbooks from source code repositories, you run the small risk of loading an alternative copy of the same version into your chef server.

---

Huh? Explain please!

Take the following scenario:

1. The chef developer makes a small change to his cookbook, but does not increment the cookbook version number, 1.1
2. You pull down what you think is version 1.1 of the cookbook.
3. The chef developer makes a more substantial change the cookbook, but again does not increment the version number (because he's not ready to release).

Your chef server now has a copy of version 1.1 that does not match the latest copy of version 1.1 in the version control system....

To complicate matters you need to explicitly run a "berks update" followed by a forced reload of the cookbook into your chef server (remember berkshelf freezes cookbooks) in order to fix this problem..... This can become a non trivial issue and I have been burned by it more than once (Bizarrely the openstack cookbooks are not available from supermarket).

At the end of the day consume from source if you're on first name terms with the other development team :-)  Another solution if you crave stability is to only consume from Git tags, a best practice that cookbooks loaded into the chef supermarket do follow.

What the Chef supermarket provides is a release management process for chef cookbooks. Git is supposed to track all changes to the files within the cookbook. But it cannot detect when a cookbook is ready for a release. That is the job of the developer and if he behaves and follows a sensible workflow he'll tag his code and then push it into some sort of repository for downloading by 3rd parties. It is this process and storage facility that supermarket provides. It's your friend I highly recommend using it :-)

Apologies for the long rant! Therapeutic :-)

Comment: will not vote in any side, the rant is partly justified as there's cookbook devs not working well and doing breaking changes in same version , but in the other hand some perfect releases never end up to supermarket as the devs have tagged on github and forget to update the supermarket ;). I think both answers are complementar, how to and why to be cautious when doing it :p

Comment: In fact I upvoted, the answer is useful on the 'why not use master branch' ;)

Comment: You can specify git commit references. This eliminates the problem of updated code without updated version numbers; except in the case of the authors force-pushing rebased code over the default branch... but then you'd have bigger problems.

Comment: @Derek commit references gives you a "point in time" but the Berkshelf lock file gives you that too. What you really need is a signal from the developer that a version has been released. That's what a tag represents. You need to know exactly which commit represents a version, cause it's not fun to reload the same cookbook version into chef server. In conclusion it's a subtle problem most devs are prob oblivious to.